# Making htpasswd usernames and passwords non case sensative

Tags: .htaccess, md5, .htpasswd

Is it possible to make htpasswd usernames and passwords non case sensitive ?

Is the achievable either by some setting in htpasswd / htacess or via the hashing algorithm (we are currently using MD5) ?

Answer (score 1):

Add below but making password non case sensitive is opening a security hole in application.

```
CheckSpelling on
```

to your `.htaccess` file
of course after enabling the RewriteEngine

so the final code will be

```
RewriteEngine on
CheckSpelling on
```

I guess it is the best and safest way.

## dont forget to change

```
AllowOverride none
```

## to

```
AllowOverride All
```

inside your `httpd.conf` file, to allow .htaccess files to work correctly.